# Count doesn't applied to -include jpg

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

I have following script:

```
$Extension = "*.jpg"
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\DAVID\Documents\Test' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $FilesInFolder = @($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include $Extension -File -Force)

    $FileSize = $FilesInFolder | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum |
                Select -ExpandProperty Sum
    $FileSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($FileSize/1MB) + " MB"

    $NumFiles = $FilesInFolder.Count
}
```

But it always counts everything in folder includes .zip files and .exe. 
What am I doing wrong here? How can I get it to count only .jpg files. Can't find any solution but I'm thinking that it has something with this line to do:

```
$FilesInFolder = @($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include $Extension -File -Force)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't fully explain this, because the docs are a little unclear on this issue but your suspicion is right. You have at least two simple ways to get the correct result:

1. Use `-Filter` instead of `-Include`

   ```
   $FilesInFolder = @($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter $Extension -File -Force)
   ```
2. Explicitly specify the path instead of using the input object

   ```
   $FilesInFolder = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Include $Extension -File -Force)
   ```

Especially the second version makes me think that this is maybe a bug (or at least very strange behaviour) in `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: or I could use Where-Object { $_.extension -eq ".jpg" }

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is $_ | Get-ChildItem is not resulting in the Path of the objects being piped to the Path property (because $_ instead has a property named PSPath).

However this seems to work:

```
$Extension = "*.jpg"

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\ab73541\Documents\' -Directory | ForEach-Object {

$FilesInFolder = @(Get-ChildItem $_.PSPath -Recurse -Include $Extension -File -Force)

$FileSize = $FilesInFolder | Measure-Object -property length -Sum | Select -ExpandProperty Sum
$FileSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($FileSize/1MB) + " MB"

$NumFiles = $FilesInFolder.Count }
```